Font in .otf format is not centered vertically
I have received some font from designers and faced the issue with vertical alignment
I added this font to my application by using Js
        const font = {
            family: `Suisse Int'l`,
            style: 'normal',
            display: 'fallback',
            weight: 500,
            src: '/assets/fonts/SuisseIntl-BlackItalic.otf',
            locale: 'Suisse',
        },

        const { family, src, ...descriptor } = font;
        const fontFace = new FontFace(family, `url(${src})`, {
            ...descriptor,
            weight: descriptor.weight.toString(),
        });

        const font = await fontFace.load().then((loadedFontFace) => {
            document.fonts.add(loadedFontFace);

            return font;
        }

        document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--font-family', `${font.family}, sans-serif`);


But after loading I can see that the font is not vertically aligned
not vertically centrered
As we can see the symbol is above baseline.
This is an example of simple sans-serif font
vertically centered
This is simple p element withoud subelements
I tried to align it vertically by using vertical-align with display: inline-clock and line-height but it did not help.
Also, when I downloaded trial version of this font from official site in .ttf format it resolved the issue and sybol bere centered as expected. Also resolved the issue ascent-override but is does not support all browsers.
Could you please assist with it and tell me what could be wrong? Because it seems for me that problem in the file in .otf format.

I could be wrong, but I feel like this might be outside the general scope of Stack Overflow. You might have to go to reddit to ask a question like this.

The answer is "because the font designer wanted it that way". The glyph is not centered by design, why I have no idea but that's the only answer you will get.

Try using a different font that is known to be good and see how that displays. If it is correct then the problem is with your font and that sort of problem is not a programming issue and would be off-topic for this site.

The vertical alignment depends on the metrics (ascender, descender, cap heights etc) as defined by the font-designer. You need to adjust the vertical alignment manually. Besides, you may encounter slightly different aligments in different browsers due to different text-rendering engines.

@Paulie_D , this font is vertically centered in Figma and designers assured me that this font is centered vertically, so this is why I thought that the font could be shifted programmatically, for instance by some unobvious global configs because it seems that I checked everything. But thank you for your reply, maybe I have to be more persistent with designers and try to ask them to check fonts with some of their tools

@herrstrietzel, thank you, I will ask designers to double-check because now I have an assumption that they did not check everything that they had to when I asked
